# Из бд в массив

Tags: c#, access, массивы, база-данных

Подскажите пожалуйста, как из бд Access (единственная таблица с 2 полями) получить значения и записать их в двумерный массив?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Формат строки подключения смотрите [тут](http://cbuilder.ru/index.php?topic=1228.0)

```
using (var cnn = new OleDbConnection(cnn_str)) 
{
  cnn.Open();
  var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM `MyTable`", cnn);

  using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
  {
    var lists = new List<object[]>();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
      var arr = new object[2];
      arr[0] = reader[0];
      arr[1] = reader[1];

      lists.Add(arr);
    }
    return lists.ToArray();
  }
}
```